# Implement tomcat in java to deploy war

Tags: java, rest, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my war using tomcat (implement in java) before running my functional test. Initially I implemented Jetty Server in java and I successfully exposed the URI and I could execute my test. But I want to deploy my war to test it and not just expose the URI,I can obviously use jetty plugin and cargo in my pom file, but I want to use tomcat to do so. I thoroughly searched online, I found sample code on deploying war using tomcat implementation in java [1], so that I can start tomcat, deploy my war and then run my functional test. But it is not clearly explained. Can I refer to any good documentation online which will help me with deploying my war using tomcat?

[1] http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat

Comment: jetty and tomcat are both servlets, so you have to use one or the other, not both. Whichever one you choose, you have to import it as a dependency in your pom file and configure it differently in your code. You won't be able to write something that runs on jetty and then deploy it on tomcat.

Comment: I guess I did not clearly explained my question. Yes, I understand both are servlets. But I want to use tomcat to deploy my war locally. I used jetty initially, but that did not deploy my war but just exposed my URI. I can deploy my war using jetty by adding a plugin as mentioned above, but instead I would prefer implementing tomcat in java to run my test.

Comment: Assuming the deployment is for automated testing you will need to use the tomcat maven plug in.

Comment: No this is not for automated testing but junit testing. I wish to implement tomcat in java to deploy my war in before scenario then run my test and stop the tomcat in after scenario.

Comment: The deployment of my service in my internal domains will be done using tomcat so I prefer doing it in my functional test too. I guess its possible to implement tomcat in java to deploy war,start it up and then stop it. But I am not sure how exactly and there is no such documentation which will help me understand the workflow. Probably I will try add the dependencies needed and go through their javadoc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your level of testing the recommended maven approach would be one of the following

For unit tests
Put any startup of maven and possibly deployment in the pretest phase

- process-test-classes

Then run the tests in the test phase

- test

This approach will work if the unit tests themselves need to be deployed to tomcat to run small parts of the code base note there is no way here to shutdown tomcat you will need to find a phase to bind the shutdown to.

For integration tests that need to run the whole war file Put any startup of maven and possibly deployment in the pre-test phases

- pre-integration-test

Run the test in the test phase

- integration-test

Undeploy and shutdown during the post test phase

- post-integration-test

Under this scenario the link you included in your question becomes relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was planning to do the things you mentioned. I found a nice document online "https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/create-a-java-web-application-using-embedded-tomcat ". This will help me understand how it works. Thanks guys.